# Error calling method on NPObject exception with google earth

Tags: javascript, websocket, google-earth

I'm trying to implement a Google Earth controller via Websockets.

I have a simple echo websockets server in c#, when i type a value in a textbox it just sends it back to the page (I plan to be able to directly send data from the server later).

My script to initialize google earth is pretty standard and works:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);
  StartServer();
}

function initCallback(instance) {
  ge = instance;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

  // add a navigation control
  ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

  // add some layers
  ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
  ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);
}

function failureCallback(errorCode) 
{

}
</script>
```

(ge variable) is just the google earth instance.

Now in my server code, if I do:

```
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
        {
            inc.innerHTML += evt.data + '<br/>';
            var lookAt =              ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
            lookAt.setLatitude(lookAt.getLatitude() + 10);
            lookAt.setLongitude(lookAt.getLongitude() + 20);
            ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
        };
```

Everything works (earth rotates a tiny bit).

Now if I do:

```
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
        {
            inc.innerHTML += evt.data + '<br/>';
            var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
            lookAt.setLatitude(lookAt.getLatitude() + evt.data); //Here i try to use the data received
            lookAt.setLongitude(lookAt.getLongitude() + 20);
            ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
        };
```

I get exception : Error calling method on NPObject

I tried to split string, convert to number, but always get the same error.

```
inc.innerHTML += evt.data + '<br/>';
```

always works tho.

EDIT:

I also tried :
    var i = parseInt(d); //Works
but then when i call l
    lookAt.setLatitude(i); //Exception

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorted, pretty stupid thing, server was sending extra characters.

Feels a bit bad to have this generic error on parsing, having something like "string format invalid" would be bit more meaningful.

Comment: That's JavaScript for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `evt.data` with `(+evt.data)`, the unary plus operator forces the value to a number.

I don't know the Google Earth API but if getLongitude was returning a string for some weird reason then that could produce the behaviour you're seeing there (string + number is a number but string + string is a string).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried but still same error. I also tried to use Number(evt.data) but no luck either, not sure if it is a security issue.

Comment: What happens when you use `+ "20"` instead of `+ 20` in the first (working) example?

Comment: using + "20" gives me npobject error. using parseFloat("20") works, using parseFloat(evt.data) still gives error

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and it turned out that the lat/long values were too precise, so I did this to turn it into the maximum 6 decimal precision equivalent:

```
function Blah(lat, lon) {
    //because the GPS is ridiculously accurate and 
    //google earth is not, we need to round to six decimals at most
    lat = Math.round(lat * 1000000) / 1000000;
    lon = Math.round(lon * 1000000) / 1000000;
```